# Laravel API CORS

Tags: php, laravel, api, cors

I created API using Laravel 5.6 and i created CORS middleware and [this  is the content of middleware](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZjHO.png) , but when access this api from another Ip address it's return the data ..

```
Route::group([

'middleware' => 'cors',

], function ($router) {


Route::get('/get_users', function(){
     return App\User::all();
});

});
```

> I registered the cors middleware in Kernal.php

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You may use [barryvdh/laravel-cors](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors) package instead of writing your own middleware.

Answer (score 1):

Just add this to the beginning of your api route file:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin : *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers : Content-Type,X-Auth-Token,Authorization,Origin');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods :GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
```

This work for me.